# Dynamic Right-Click Menu C# Based on Location

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

Okay, so what I am looking to do is to have a menu that preforms certain actions based on file location. So, if a file was in the folder that my application uses, I would want Move to Documents, and if a file was at that location, Move to [Program Folder]. This context menu would be able through Explorer.

Anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

At least as a base, I think that I would have to use a context menu and I could dynamically add items... or at least that is how I think I would have to do it.

[Edit: July 20, 2012 10:17] - Perhaps my question was phrased poorly. What I am looking to do is have my program be more integrated with Explorer, so when the user right clicks on files certain actions appear, and this is based on whether or not the file is associated with the program I am developing.

Comment: More info needed: Are you trying to add an item to the menu that Explorer shows when you right-click an item? Or is it just shows within a program you've written?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, this is to be used in Explorer.

Comment: Shell extensions such as this are added as entries into the Windows Registry, not as .NET applications.  What does your question have to do with C# and .NET?

Comment: I wasn't sure how to go about this, and with the items being referred to as part of the right click context menu, I thought I might be going through a C# application to add things to the context menu. So what you are saying is, that I need to write a shell extension to add items dynamically to the right click context menu and then have those items call forms or exe which I write?

Answer (score 1):

To add items to the Explorer context menu, you need to use a shell extension.  Here is a guide to writing shell extensions:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/830/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens

Part VI describes adding to the "Send-To" menu, which sounds like what you're looking for.